# Find the difference between 2 numbers as the as a % increase of the lower number - excel

Tags: excel, percentage

Ive got 2 numbers in a spreadsheet like this

```
__A_|__B__
    |
700 | 900
```

What im trying to do is find the how much of an increase 900 is as a % of 700.

The current way i work it out is :

- 900 - 700 = 200
- 700/100 = 7
- 200/7 = 28.57% increase

This is tedious as it requires a block of formulas that interact or i just end up doing by hand. Is there a simple 1 formula line approach to do the same ?

---

For reference ive created a google spreadsheet to test formulas in here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1Bj-kkjEntx_AYhV7zPD3bhFe-4vPbGXWBsAe3YuOY/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cell `C1` put the following formula:

`=(B1-A1)/A1`

Basically, % change should be calculated by first determining the difference between the amounts, then divide by the original amount.